# Name for union of upsets/downsets

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, terminology

Set of lower bounds in poset is defined like $ A^l = \{ x \in P : \forall a \in A . x \le a \} = \bigcap_{a \in A} \{ x \in P : x \le a \}$.

Is there in literature a name for union  $ \bigcup_{a \in A} \{ x \in P : x \le a \} $?

Comment: What you call "set of upper bounds" for $A$ looks suspiciosly like the set of lower bounds for the set $A$...

Comment: Looks like a kind of order ideal to me, no?

Comment: Google gives a few hits for the obvious "downset generated by $A$". Some people seem to use the notation $A \downarrow$ or $\downarrow A$.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez - Fixed, thank you for correction

@JBL - Yes, that is it, thank you very much.

@Chris Eagle - Yes, I'm googling now with your keywords, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Introduction to Lattices and Order* by B. A. Davey and H. A. Priestly calls this $\mathord{\downarrow}A$ or *the downset of $A$* and also uses $\mathord{\downarrow} a$ for $\{x \in P : x \le a\}$

Comment: I don't know the etiquette on this: is my inclusion of a citation enough to turn Chris Eagle's comment into an answer?

Comment: You gave an (accepted, so presumably good) answer, and Chris Eagle gave a good comment.  It's Chris's responsibility to post an answer if he wants, but a good rule is to mention in your answer something like "Inspired by Chris Eagle's comment above, I went and found ...", or "Following Chris Eagle's observation in an earlier comment, ..." . That way Chris can (vicariously) enjoy the acceptance/added reputation.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.23